# How to exclude a perticular field from unique validation in edit mode in cakephp3.0 validation

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I want to validate a field called `survey_id` which is an input from user for uniqueness. It is working properly and giving the correct response when adding the new record, but when I tried to edit this record it is giving an error `[unique] => Provided value already exist`. So what I want is to exclude the `survey_id` of the current record from uniqueness check and if user input some other value for `survey_id` it should check for uniqueness search.

Currently I am using the CakePHP 3.0 validation with on create validation. Here is the validation rule that I am using:

```
validator
        ->requirePresence('survey_id', __('msg_required'))
        ->notEmpty('survey_id', __('msg_required'))
        ->maxlength('survey_id', 32, __('msg_maxlength'))    
        ->add('survey_id', 'unique', ['rule' =>   ['validateUnique',['id']], 'provider' => 'table', 'message' => 'Provided value already exist', 'on'=>'create']);

return $validator;
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance.
   `

Comment: My use case is if the user edits other details but does not change the survey_id? Well this fails validation because it won't be unique! The survey_id exists in the db, it belongs to the very user trying to change other aspects of his profile. How can we handle this? or if the user changes and provide some other survey_id it should check for uniqueness check excluding the current  survey_id

Comment: You need to create custom validation method to  get this done. please refer this https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules
please also check for buildRules() in you table/model.

Comment: Hi justrohu I tried to create a custom validation  but how it possible to pass the current id of the table in order to excluding it from current context

     $validator
             ->add('survey_id', 'custom', [
                    'rule' => function ($value, $id) use ($id) {
                          $data = $this->getSurveyId($value, array($id));
                          return (!empty($data)) ? false : true;
                    },
                    'message' => 'The title is not valid'
                ]); so how to get $id  in this context

Comment: for an edit the current id of the table is present in $context / request data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work with this validation rule

```
$validator
        ->requirePresence('survey_id', __('msg_required'))
        ->notEmpty('survey_id', __('msg_required'))
        ->maxlength('survey_id', 32, __('msg_maxlength'))
        ->alphaNumeric('survey_id', __('msg_surveyid_format'))
        ->add('survey_id', 'custom', [
            'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
              if (!empty($context['data']['projectId'])) { $values = array($context['data']['projectId']); } else { $values = array(); }
              $data = $this->getSurveyId($value, $values);
              return (!empty($data)) ? false : true;
            },
              'message' => __('msg_surveyid_exsist')]);

        return $validator;
      }

public function getSurveyId($surveyId = null, $exclude = null) {

        $where = array('p.survey_id' => $surveyId);
        if (!empty($exclude) && is_array($exclude)) {
          $where[] = array('p.id NOT IN' => $exclude);
        }
        return $this->db->newQuery()
                        ->select('*')
                        ->from(['p' => 'projects'])
                        ->where($where)
                        ->execute()
                        ->fetch('assoc');
      }
```

Comment: Better than creating anonymous function AND public method would be to create just method. It would be more readable in my opinion: `->add('survey_id', 'custom', [$this, 'validateSurveyId'])` and put all logic there.